# Whitespaces appear at the end of a string when unit testing

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

So I ran into this strange problem here. We built a parser upon `NSXMLParser` that first instantiates an object and then sets its values depending on what XML element just ended. Basically, it transforms an XML file into a reusable `NSObject`.

Now I set a breakpoint in the parser to determine, if the values are set correctly.

[image: Screenshot debugger]

Well, that looks nice. Correctly parsed. Let me write a unit test for that.

```
assertThat([parsedPerson dateOfBirth], is(equalTo(@"22.06.1949")));
```

Now this happens. I get the following console output:

```
Expected "22.06.1949", but was "22.06.1949        "
```

What? Where do the whitespaces come from? Let me debug the object in the unit test.

[image: Screenshot debugger 2]

Same memory address? Same object? Where do the whitespaces come from? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: In the test, where does this string value come from?

Comment: It's essentially the same object taken from the parser. The parser initiates the object, assigns the string values, I take the very same object and read the string values. But it's not only in testing, I'll edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it's related to the parser itself and the whitespaces were actually real whitespaces in the XML file.

We have (had) the following setup:

```
- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName attributes: (NSDictionary *) attributeDict {
    [self setCurrentString: [NSMutableString string]];
}

- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters: (NSString *) string {
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\t" withString: @""];
    [currentString appendString: string];
}

- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didEndElement: (NSString *) elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString: @"dateOfBirth"]) {
        [theObject setDateOfBirth: currentString];
    }

        // ...
}
```

Now the problem is, assigning the `NSMutableString currentString` to this object is dangerous at this place, since it will be modified by the `foundCharacters` method as it continues to find characters AFTER the element ended.

The misunderstanding here was, that the mutable string would not be modified after it was assigned to the object.

Solution: Make a non-mutable string from a string, when you really want it to not be modified, even if you think it won't.

```
- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didEndElement: (NSString *) elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName {

    NSString *parsedString = [NSString stringWithString:currentString]; // non-mutable copy made here

    if ([elementName isEqualToString: @"dateOfBirth"]) {
        [theObject setDateOfBirth: parsedString];
    }

        // ...
}
```

Comment: Good find, but you shouldn't need to do that. Is `dateOfBirth` a property? Any time you have a property of NSString, make it a "copy" property. The same goes with any property where the type is immutable but has an mutable subclass.